# Bound for a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have run into the following problem:

Prove that if $0<|z|<1$ then $\frac{1}{4}|z|<|e^z-1|<\frac{7}{4}|z|$.

I already obtained the upper bound : Notice that the function $f(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{z}$ is holomorphic on the unit disk (it has a removable singularity at $z=0$) and has no zeros there. By the maximum/minimum principle it attains the extremal values at the unit circle and for $|z|=1$ we have $$|f(z)|=\frac{|e^z-1|}{|z|}=|\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}|\leq\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}|\frac{z^k}{k!}|=e^{|z|}-1=e-1<\frac{7}{4}.$$ The best lower bound I obtained is not good enough: for $|z|=1$
$$|f(z)|=\frac{|e^z-1|}{|z|}=|\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}|\geq|z|-\Sigma_{k=2}^\infty|\frac{z^k}{k!}|\geq|z|-(e^{|z|}-|z|-1|)=3-e.$$ But $3-e<\frac{1}{4}$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Koebe quarter theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_1/4_theorem

Comment: Koebe quarter theorem solves the problem. Thanks!!!!